# Javascript - Soma e Group By em Array

Tags: javascript, json, array, group-by

Gostaria de uma dica/ajuda.

Estou trabalhando com uma série de arquivos `JSON`, e aplicando filtros nos mesmos conforme o usuário vai avançando no sistema.

Até aí tudo bem, consegui fazer tranquilamente usando o `.filter()`.

Meu problema está no passo seguinte a este. Preciso aplicar o filtro neste arquivo, e com o resultado do filtro, sumarizar a informação com base em algumas colunas apenas.

```
var as=$(ards).filter(function (i,n){
    return n.ARMARIO_ERB===marker.getTitle();
});
```

OK, o filtro está aplicado, confome o marcador que preciso, neste ponto imprimo as informações do filtro:

```
for (var i=0;i<as.length;i++){
    conteudo_info +=    "<tr>" +
                          "<td>" + as[i].UF + "</td>" +
                          "<td>" + as[i].DESC_CLUSTER + "</td>" +
                          "<td>" + as[i].DESC + "</td>" +
                          "<td>" + as[i].QNTD1+ "</td>" +
                          "<td>" + as[i].QNTD2+ "</td>" +
                        "</tr>" ;
}
```

Coloquei cinco colunas apenas para simplificar, tenho em torno de 10.

O que preciso fazer é, em vez de apresentar as 10 colunas, gostaria de apresentar o resultado de maneira consolidada.

Exemplo(Base Original):

```
PR CTBA  A 1 1
PR CTBA  B 8 5
PR MGA   A 1 2
PR CTBA  C 2 0
```

Consolidada:

```
PR CTBA 11 6
PR MGA  1  2
```

Pesquisando, vi que pode ser feito através do `.reduce()`, achei alguns exemplos, mas não consegui aplicar nenhum, sou leigo no assunto.

Achei este link: [sum-and-group-by-of-json-data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11199884/1898543), ele aplica sobre uma coluna apenas, como eu faria para 4 por exemplo, somando minhas colunas?

Exemplo do link:

```
var result = dataObject.reduce(function(res, obj) {
    if (!(obj.category in res))
        res.__array.push(res[obj.category] = obj);
    else {
        res[obj.category].hits += obj.hits;
        res[obj.category].bytes += obj.bytes;
    }
    return res;
}, {__array:[]}).__array
                .sort(function(a,b) { return b.bytes - a.bytes; });
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Para fazer estes tipos de operações eu utilizo a [biblioteca jLinq](http://www.hugoware.net/projects/jlinq), veja se lhe ajuda! Não uma documentação muito boa, mas é bem útil.

Comment: @Fernando cheguei a dar uma olhada nesta biblioteca.. Parece interessante, mas como só neste ponto irei utilizar esta consolidação, estou tentando fazer com o .reduce().. Em ultimo caso vou tentar com o jLink. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu implementei uma solução com 'Vanilla JS' (Javascript puro :p ).

Segue:

```
//Classe de agrupamento
function Foo(){
    // data source
    this.data = [];

    // retorna um array de objetos agrupados por propertyNames
    // propertyNames [array de string] - nomes das propriedades de agrupamento
    this.getGroupedData = function(propertyNames){
        if(!this.data.length || !propertyNames || !propertyNames.length) return [];

        var group = [], currentIndex, currentItem;

        for(var i in this.data){
            currentIndex = getGroupedItemIndex(group, propertyNames, this.data[i]);
            if(currentIndex >= 0){
                currentItem = group[currentIndex];
            }else{
                currentItem = {};
                for(var pi in propertyNames){
                    currentItem[propertyNames[pi]] = this.data[i][propertyNames[pi]];
                }
                currentItem.TOTAL_QNTD1 = 0;
                currentItem.TOTAL_QNTD2 = 0;
            }

            currentItem.TOTAL_QNTD1 += this.data[i].QNTD1;
            currentItem.TOTAL_QNTD2 += this.data[i].QNTD2;

            if(currentIndex >= 0){
                group[currentIndex] = currentItem;
            }else{
                group.push(currentItem);
            }
        }

        return group;
    }

    var getGroupedItemIndex = function(array, propertyNames, targetItem){
        var index = -1, found = true;

        for(var i in array){        
            for(var pi in propertyNames){
                found &= (array[i][propertyNames[pi]] === targetItem[propertyNames[pi]]);
            }
            if(found){
                index = i;
                break;
            }               

             // reset do valor para a próxima iteração
             found = true;
        }

        return index;
    }
}
```

Agora só resta instanciar, passar os dados e obter os itens agrupados.

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.data = [{UF: 'PR', DESC_CLUSTER: 'CTBA', DESC: 'A', QNTD1: 1, QNTD2: 1}, {UF: 'PR', DESC_CLUSTER: 'CTBA', DESC: 'B', QNTD1: 8, QNTD2: 5}, {UF: 'PR', DESC_CLUSTER: 'MGA', DESC: 'A', QNTD1: 1, QNTD2: 2}, {UF: 'PR', DESC_CLUSTER: 'CTBA', DESC: 'C', QNTD1: 2, QNTD2: 0} ];

// obtém os dados agrupados por UF e DESC_CLUSTER
var groupedData = foo.getGroupedData(['UF', 'DESC_CLUSTER']);
//para melhor visualização no console: table(groupedData);
```

Comment: Bruno, excelente. Fiz um teste aqui, estou recebendo uma mensagem de erro. Analisando um pouco mais, coloquei para printar o `currentItem`, o array possui 3 objetos, ele está imprimindo os 3 e mais 2 fantasmas(`undefined`), e recebo o erro: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'UF' of undefined`. Como posso tratar?

Comment: Aparece desta forma: (Cada // Pula linha)

`Object {UF: "TO", DESC_CLUSTER: "PALMAS", QNTD1: 0, QNTD2: 0}`
//
`Object {UF: "TO", DESC_CLUSTER: "PALMAS", QNTD1: 1, QNTD2: 1}`
//
`Object {UF: "TO", DESC_CLUSTER: "PALMAS", QNTD1: 2, QNTD2: 2}`
//
`Object {UF: undefined, DESC_CLUSTER: undefined, QNTD1: 0, QNTD2: 0}`
//
`Object {UF: undefined, DESC_CLUSTER: undefined, QNTD1: 0, QNTD2: 0}`

Comment: Hum, estranho...

Tu poderias criar um [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) com a situação, Fernando? 

Acredito que será mais fácil para nós chegarmos a uma solução.

Comment: De qualquer modo, vejo que é necessário verificar se o objeto possui as propriedades antes de lê-las (usando reflection: object.hasOwnProperty('NOME_DA_PROPRIEDADE') ), caso não haja garantia da existência de determinadas propriedades. Além, claro, de verificar se é válido. Não fiz nada disso para simplificar o código, mas recomendo a implementação.

Comment: Bruno, vou tentar implementar isto. Sou leigo no assunto, mas entendi o que é preciso. Caso não consiga, crio um JsFiddle com um exemplo. Obrigado novamente.

Comment: Fiz um JsFiddle, ele não esta agrupando direito, devo ter feito algo errado, você poderia dar uma olhada? [jsfiddle-Fernando](https://jsfiddle.net/finando/36whkab3/). Está imprimindo no console a tabela. Obrigado.

Comment: Só pude olhar agora. Demorei mas corrigi =) Atualizei minha resposta com a correção e adicionei uma citação com uma breve explicação.

Comment: Atualizei o seu [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36whkab3/3/) com a correção do código e as referências de scripts

Comment: Cara, sensacional. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, fico lhe devendo uma hahahaha. Obrigado mesmo.